# Force caching of partial content in html5 video player for mp4 videos

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I'm using video.js v7.18.0 to play mp4 videos in my browser page stored in azure blob storage container, when the user moves to a random part of the video using the seek bar the browser emits a request to fetch the content, the request header contains:

`Range: bytes=78020608-`

The server responds with `206 Partial Content` status code and the response header contains:

`Content-Range: bytes 72908800-335369133/335369134`

The problem is: content is always re-fetched when the user seeks to a previously visited part of the video, the content is stored only for the current buffered part but not kept for later. Not really a problem for small videos but for big videos (>300Mb) it becomes really slow.

Is there a way to force the player to cache previously fetched content of a video or intercept programmatically requests with `Range` header, fetch the content, store it as a blob into an IndexedDb on browser-side to be served later?
I'm trying to avoid switching to HLS of DASH since the amount of mp4 in the blob storage is significant.